# Fibonacci induction proof?

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

The Fibonacci Numbers $(f_n)$ are defined $f_1=f_2=1$, and $f_n=f_{n-1}+f_{n-2} ,\,\,\,\forall n \geq2$.

Prove that for every integer $n \geq 1$,
$$f_1 +f_2 +···+f_n =f_{n+2}−1$$

Comment: ① The correct HTML representation of subscript is `f<sub>1</sub>`, the "/" preceeds the "sub" at the end, however ② we support TeX here, you could just write `$f_1 = f_2 = 1$` as so on.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried so far?

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $f_2 = 1$, the conclusion is true for $n = 0$, for the induction suppose $\sum_{k=1}^n f_k = f_{n+2} - 1$ holds for some $n \ge 0$, then we have
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} f_k &= \sum_{k=1}^n f_k + f_{n+1}\\
          &= f_{n+2} - 1 + f_{n+1}\\
          &= f_{n+3} - 1
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

$$f_n-f_{n-1}=f_{n-2},\,\,\,\,\color{Red}{\text{Telescope}}$$

Comment: [Telescoping series](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FTelescoping_series&ei=GyMVVeCnLIT-8QWe94CYDQ&usg=AFQjCNE6VcOM7CyoIW4wkXgdbQdZQGaoGQ)

Answer (score 0):

$f_1 +f_2 +···+f_n =f_{n+2}−1 \to f_1 +f_2 +···+f_n =f_n + f_{n+1}−1$, so:

$f_1 +f_2 +···+f_{n-1} =f_{n+1}−1$.

Repeat until $f_1=f_3-1$, which is true ($f_3=2$).

Comment: this is not really a proof by induction

Comment: $P(n) \to P(n-1)$, so by induction $P(n+1) \to P(n)$